# Get assigned platforms to Azure B2C application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Is it any other way to get assigned platforms to application in AADB2C except following?

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myorganization/applications?$filter=appId eq 'guid id'

If I add multiple platforms like IOS/Desktop/Android all redirects uris for them land in the same b2c applications property `publicClient: redirectUris[]` I need to know which uri is for which platform type and I do not want to achieve this by guessing based on specific redirect uri structure.

Comment: No. Looks like the platform information doesn't exist in the application / service principal resource type.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write your own logic to determine which redirect Uri belongs to which app. Or another cleaner alternative is to have multiple apps, one per platform. There is no additional cost to having a separate app per platform each with a single redirect Uri. And that may give you additional flexibility to support different auth flows or configuration in case of library updates or changes.